# JQuery Ajax POST not sending data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

The issue is, the POST doesn't appear to send information to the PHP script. The firebug console shows the information is passed from JavaScript and appears to be formatted properly, but I'm not getting a response, nor is the PHP script running.

The PHP itself works fine, however.

The Jquery:

```
$(function(){
        $('#submit-item').live("click",function(){
            var productName = $(".add-item-form #productName").val();
            var category = $(".add-item-form #categorySelect").val();
            var brandName = $(".add-item-form #brandName").val();
            var volume = $(".add-item-form #volumeType").val();


            $.post("addNewProduct.php",{productName:productName ,category: category, brandName: brandName, volume: volume});
        });
    });
```

And the HTML form:

```
<section id="add-item-pane" class="secondary">
    <header>
        <h1>add item</h1>
        <a href="#" class="close-secondary"></a>
    </header>
    <form class="add-item-form" method="POST" action="" accept-charset=utf-8>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="productName">product name</label>
            <input type="text" name="productName" id="productName" placeholder="Product Name">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="categorySelect" required>category</label>
            <select name="categorySelect" id="categorySelect" placeholder="Category" required>
                <option value="1">ATERIA-AINEKSET JA KASTIKKEET</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="brandName">brand name</label>
            <input type="text" name="brandName" id="brandName" placeholder="Brand Name">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="volumeType">volume type</label>

            <label for="volumeTypeKG">g/kg</label>
            <input type="radio" name="volumeType" id="volumeType" value="1">
            <label for="volumeTypeL">ml/l</label>
            <input type="radio" name="volumeType" id="volumeType" value="2">

        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Add it" id="submit-item">


    </form>
</section>
```

The receiving PHP:

```
$productName =  $_POST['productName'];
$categoryId =  $_POST['category'];
$brandId =  $_POST['brandName'];
$volumeId =  $_POST['volume'];
```

Comment: Please post the part of `addNewProduct.php` where you retrieve the POST parameters.

Comment: You shouldn't be using jQuery.live() as it is depreciated in jQuery 1.7: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Wiz You mean it's deprecated?  Software can't really depreciate, as it has no real "value"...

Comment: Added the receiving PHP, and cheers @Wiz I'll remove that.

Comment: @Wiz actually, some countries' legislation states that software CAN be depreciated on accounting books just like buildings and other fixed assets. (A nice off-topic, this one)

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the data once it hits the php?  I'd suggest looking into this article a bit: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs in your code:

1) You have 2 inputs with the same **id**, by definition, an ID should be unique in the page.

```
<input type="radio" name="volumeType" id="volumeType" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="volumeType" id="volumeType" value="2">
```

If you want to retrieve the value of the **selected** radio, you should add a CSS class to each radio button like "myRadioGroup" and retrieve the value with:

`$(".myRadioGroup:checked").val()`

2) You have a form pointing on itself (with `action=""`) and you have a `input type="submit"`. so when you click the button "Add it", The listener start the job, but you don't stop the submit event, which submit the form and reload the same page.

Try to replace your:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add it" id="submit-item">
```

with a simple button which will not start any submit event.

```
<button type="button" id="submit-item">Add it</button>
```

Moreover, the form is useless in your case because you don't use it to serialize your data. You can remove the form too.

When you will click on the button, it will not submit anything, and you AJAX call will be sent.

Comment: To expand on that, using ".add-item-form #productName" in the jquery is a bit unnecessary because, like you mentioned, ID's should be unique.  "#productName" should be enough.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense after a little explanation. Forms are still something of a pain for me.